# how to update Cart Options in Codeigniter?

Tags: codeigniter

Through Documents provided by Codeigniter Its Cart Library doesnt Update its options We can add the Options like that

```
$data = array(
           array(
                   'id'      => 'sku_123ABC',
                   'qty'     => 1,
                   'price'   => 39.95,
                   'name'    => 'T-Shirt',
                   'options' => array('Size' => 'L', 'Color' => 'Red')
                )
        );

$this->cart->insert($data);
```

Is there any other way or any tutorial to learn how we can update  options of Cart just like

```
$qid = $this->input->post("qid");
$pairs = $this->input->post("pairs");
$males = $this->input->post("males");
$females = $this->input->post("females");

    $data = array(
        array(
            'rowid'   => $qid,
            'qty'     => 1,
            'options'  => array('pairs' => $pairs, 'males' => $males, 'females' => $females))
    );

    $this->cart->update($data);
```

I have searched it but seems no one has made any fix for it?

Comment: Please note that Options given are just dummies I know they are different from each other in update and insert function

Answer (score 1):

Though I have not found any solution therefore I am using simple solution and that is just rest the item in cart and adding new item with same id and updated option values. Its not great trick though but it is just working for me.

Answer (score 0):

I am fallen yesterday like this kind of problem then i create Extending / Override update function. Here how to Extending Native library Link : [Create CI Library](https://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/general/creating_libraries.html)

Here is my modified code in [Github Link](https://github.com/geeklycan/cicartoptions)

I hope it will help someone and also can modify as their need.

Answer (score 0):

No it did not work for me.. but there is no any errors, I check the array within the _update function as well,

```
Array
(
    [id] => 177
    [rowid] => 66bd8895e10f189f62bf3a65ada83630
    [qty] => 1
    [options] => Array
        (
            [vat] => 0
            [discount] => 0
        )

)
```

Answer (score 0):

I know i'ts just too late but I want to share my solution:

I just got the the options in an array and updated it as I wanted and then update the entire options field in the cart with the array content.

Hope this help somebody.

Sorry for the english.

Answer (score 0):

The way I tried was a bit difficult but it works. You can’t just update a single option value. To update you have to pass all the existing values to all the option values with the value you want to update as well.

If you want to update your Size option

$data = array(
       ‘rowid’ => $yourRowIdHere,
       ‘options’ => array ( ‘color’ => $yourExistingValue, ‘length’     => $yourExistingValue, ‘size’ => $newUpdatedValue)
));

$this->cart->update($data);

Give it a try :)